# Vue.js data() properties are sync after load values using axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm using axios to load an array of strings:

```
beforeCreate () {
  this.$http
    .get('hashtags')
    .then(response => {
      this.tags = response.data.hashtags
      this.selectTags= response.data.hashtags
    })
}
```

I'm using two properties because I will use one of them for create a list of checkboxes and the other to store checked checkboxes. Initially, all checkboxes will be checked.

The problem: if I deleted one option from `selectTags` (using Google Chrome Vue panel), the same option is deleted from `tag` property.

This problem only occours when using axios. In the example bellow, I can edit one property without change the other.

```
beforeCreate () {
   this.tags = ['a', 'b', 'c']
   this.foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both properties are referencing the same array object.

A common solution is to create a copy of it, either using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
// ...
      this.tags = [...response.data.hashtags]
      this.selectTags= [...response.data.hashtags]
//...
```